# Zombie movie that takes place on each season and I can’t find it

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

A while ago (more than 3 years), I have seen a zombie movie which I just can’t find again.

I remember that the movie was split in 4 parts, each part taking place in one of each season. I remember that in winter a man finds a house with a kid inside. The kid tells him that he has been living by himself since the outbreak began and his parents and brother are dead. After a while they decide to leave the house, because they had no supplies left. I also remember a woman that was living in a farm by herself. She had managed to capture a zombie and keep his as her guard. She even named him. One night 3 guys attack her, but she manages to kill them. Also in Autumm I believe, a man that is being sick is taking inside a safehouse by some survivors. They had a doctor and I remember the building was made with bricks. Also after some time I think the sick man wanted to leave desperately, but I don't remember why. In the last part of the movie the kid, and the man are being killed by the woman in the farm, because she thought they were going to attack her again while they were passing by her farm.

The movies seemed to be fan-made or something like that, or low budget, and also it didn't seem to have known actors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [The Year After Infection](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2082478/) (2012).

> **Four stories, represented by each season, with diverse groups of
>   people and the challenges they face after a zombie apocalypse.** Trying
>   to create a new life under the most dire of circumstances and dealing
>   with letting go of their former lives, while coping with the constant
>   danger of the infected. Will they survive? Will they want to?

Comment: Yes,this is the movie.Thank you.

Comment: @hehexd - [Glad to hear it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)